# Div's not in grid

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I want to create a website, with a photos page on it. In the photos page I'm hoping to have a grid of pictures like in Instagram's:

[image]

But this is not working, it ends with the divs on the Title page, not where their parents div is:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```css
.PhotosPage{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.Photos_Container{
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;

}

.Photos{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div className="PhotosPage">
  <div className="Photos_Container">
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
    <div className="Photo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using react? Because `className` is not correct HTML

Comment: yes i am using react

Comment: can you also include code to the title section?

Comment: Corey Gibson this does not work, it still come out with the same outcome

Comment: the title page code is:Photos_TitlePage{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Photos_Title{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4.6rem;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

Comment: please add that as an edit to the question for better visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Photos` should be `.Photo`

```css
.PhotosPage{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.Photos_Container{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;

}

.Photo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="PhotosPage">
  <div class="Photos_Container">
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
    <div class="Photo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: he is using react so that is valid syntax